# Is there a way to execute MATLAB Figure window menu items via command?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I found a neat bit of code for setting drawing tools via callback:

[draw.m](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53139-draw) .

### Edit

My apologies - I didn't realize that the `Name` property was a red herring - it is the `annotation` call that enables drawing the various figures.
So my corrected question is: is there a way to execute other menu item commands, such as `set(gcf,'Some_property','Rotate 3D')` ?

Comment: In what version of MATLAB does this actually work?

Comment: @Suever My apologies for misleading you as well as myself.  Please see highly edited version of this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to execute a menu item's command is to get a handle to the menu item and then inspect the `Callback` property to see what it calls internally.

```
rotate_menu = findall(gcf, 'type', 'uimenu', 'tag', 'figMenuRotate3D');
rotate_menu.Callback

%   'toolsmenufcn Rotate'
```

As you can see this uses an internal function `toolsmenufcn` which we could call directly to activate the tool.

```
toolsmenufcn(gcf, 'Rotate')
```

If you actually look at the contents of `toolsmenufcn.m` (`edit toolsmenufcn`), you will see a list of all available commands.

Using the `toolsmenufcn` directly is of course undocumented so use at your own risk. On the other hand, dynamically retrieving and executing the `Callback` for the menu should work across versions.